# Selection Changed Event in DataGridComboBoxColumn

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a Data grid with DatagridComboBoxColumn , and i want to Fire Event SelectionChanged when user Select any thing From the ComboBox , Do Some operations ,
how can i do that any advice ,
thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can handle your DataGridView's [`EditingControlShowing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxeditingcontrol.aspx#Y26662) event and cast the editing control to the ComboBox being displayed and then wire up its `SelectionChangeCommitted` event.  Use the `SelectionChangeCommitted` handler do you what you need to do.

See the sample code in the MSDN article I linked for details.

Two important notes:

1. Despite the MSDN article's sample code it's best to use the
   ComboBox `SelectionChangeCommitted` event, as discussed [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/453d7584-d4d3-495b-b3ed-5998758d9614/) and in the
   comments of the linked MSDN article.
2. If you have more than one `DatagridComboBoxColumn` in your 
   DataGridView you might want to determine which fired either your
   `EditingControlShowing` or the ComboBox's `SelectionChangeCommitted`
   event.  You can do this by checking your DGV
   `CurrentCell.ColumnIndex` property value.

I reworked the MSDN sample code a bit to show what I mean:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
    ' Only for a DatagridComboBoxColumn at ColumnIndex 1.
    If DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
        Dim combo As ComboBox = CType(e.Control, ComboBox)
        If (combo IsNot Nothing) Then
            ' Remove an existing event-handler, if present, to avoid 
            ' adding multiple handlers when the editing control is reused.
            RemoveHandler combo.SelectionChangeCommitted, New EventHandler(AddressOf ComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted)

            ' Add the event handler. 
            AddHandler combo.SelectionChangeCommitted, New EventHandler(AddressOf ComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim combo As ComboBox = CType(sender, ComboBox)
    Console.WriteLine("Row: {0}, Value: {1}", DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex, combo.SelectedItem)
End Sub
```

Comment: I had long been waiting for a solution as well, Thank you works perfectly!

Comment: Comprehensive answer. Thumbs and score up!