# Populate dropdown from database, which is place inside Gridview in Windows Application using c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

How to populate a drop down from database which is placed inside a gridview  and handle the selected index change event of that drop down in windows application using c#

Comment: Windows application or ASP.NET web application? You've said windows application but then tagged asp.net. So it's unclear what technology you're referring to. Anyway your question is a bit broad - this isn't a free "write-my-code" site...you're expected to make some effort. You can easily find tutorials, documentation etc. which will show you each of the steps you've mentioned in your description. What is stopping you from doing such basic research and then attempting something before asking others to show you for free?

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I am only struggling with how to handle selectedindexchanged event of dropdown which is placed inside a gridview

Comment: Ok but that doesn't answer any of my questions

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the IList implementation with the dropdown or combo box.
Instead of enum.getvalues, you can bind any IList and specify the display property name.

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn CreateComboBoxWithEnums()
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    combo.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Title));
    combo.DataPropertyName = "Title";
    combo.Name = "Title";
    return combo;
}
```

Then use below code to add the column to the grid view columns collection

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(CreateComboBoxWithEnums());
```

Please note that Unlike the ComboBox control, the DataGridViewComboBoxCell does not have SelectedIndex and SelectedValue properties. Instead, selecting a value from a drop-down list sets the cell Value property.

Reference: [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Thanks, Can you suggest how to handle selectedIndexChanged Event of the dropdown which is inside the gridview?

Comment: You need to use selection changed committed.  Refer [this link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953006/selection-changed-event-in-datagridcomboboxcolumn?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have already got how to populate combobox inside Datagridview. You can try this to handle selected index change of Datagridview Combobox as shown below.

```
private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
        try
        {
            int column=excelGridview.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
            int row = excelGridview.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            int country = Convert.ToInt32(((ComboBox)sender).SelectedValue);

            if (column == 7)
            {
                MyConnect myCnn = new MyConnect();  
                String connString = myCnn.getConnect().ToString();


                SqlConnection conn;
                SqlCommand command;
                conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
                command = new SqlCommand();


                if (country > 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();

                        string query = "select regionID FROM  countryinfo country  WHERE country.ID=" + country + "";

                        command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

                        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        dt.Load(reader);

                        var currentcell = excelGridview.CurrentCellAddress;
                        DataGridViewComboBoxCell cel = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)excelGridview.Rows[currentcell.Y].Cells[8];

                        cel.Value = Convert.ToInt64(dt.Rows[0]["regionID"]);

                        conn.Close();

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex1)
                    {
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (conn != null)
                        {
                            conn.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { }           
}
```

You can get help from [**here**](https://www.aspforums.net/Threads/900854/Cascading-ComboBox-inside-DataGridView-in-Windows-Application/)

It looks like as shown in below image

[image]